# Time until it's 10 am again

Tags: android, date, time, push-notification, alarm

I am trying to post a notification every day at 10 am.
The notification is sent daily already, but not at 10 am, so I need to calculate the time to wait until its 10 am again for my AlarmManager.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
long target = dateFormat.parse("10:00").getTime();
```

I tried this, but the timestamp I get is 50 years or so ago... (I think it is the time of the first time it was 10 am after the timestamp started counting)

So how do I calculate the milliseconds to wait until it is 10 am again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Calendar` instead of `SimpleDateFormat` for time-manipulation purposes.

In order to find 10AM on the next day:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance()
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10) // For 10AM
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1) // Add 1 to date == tomorrow

final Date d = c.getTime()
// Do what you want with the date
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take one Calendar object and set Hour of the day 10 AM than should get time from that calendar object like calender.getTime() it will return long and it will be set as setRepeating(calender.getTime()) while setting alarm manager.